# Navigation Menu using php/mysql/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, navigation, content-management-system

I'm making a CMS for my website and I am now making the Navigation part, can somebody give me tips or links to a tutorial on how to make my navigation menu dynamic? Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="Home.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="VirtualTours/VirtualTour.php"><span>Virtual Tour</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Trivia.php"><span>Trivia</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Learnmore.php"><span>Learn More</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Albums.php"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
<li><a href="FAQs.php"><span>FAQs</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some tips:

1) In database create table witch contains menu elements (eg. label and link).

2) In PHP create code witch get data from database, put it into JSON and "echo" it (json).

3) In HTML/JAVASCRIPT file, using for eg. jQuery, get JSON data from PHP by AJAX and put it into menu in "complete" listener. Ajax part should look simmilar to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'fileFromPoint2.php/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).complete(function(jsonData) {
        // here you should write code which puts data from jsonData to your dynamic menu.
    });
```

I hope it will be clear for you :)